# Carat position in a textarea in IE11 in Document mode 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-11

Pulling my hair out.  How do I get the carat position within a text area on IE 11 that is in Document mode 7 (and no I can't change the mode).

Have tried the many solutions suggested in stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web.  Some solutions got close, some didn't work at all.

Needs to work where ever the carat is and if a selection is highlighted.

Please test your proposed solution before posting it as every solution I have tried does not work.

Comment: Hi, you haven't provided any code examples of what you have tried so far... assuming you have tried debugging your markup and code with the f12 dev tool, make sure that you do not have carret browsing turned on in your browser (f7). I've posted a sample javascript in the answer box below.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSelectedText(){
  if(document.selection){// IE8 and earlier
    var selection = document.selection;
    var newRng = selection.createRange();
    newRng.select();
    newRng.innerHTML='<mark>'+newRng.text+'<\/mark>';
    return newRng.text;
  }else{// other browsers and IE9 and higher.
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
var mrk = document.createElement("mark");
//mrk.style.color = "yellow";
mrk.appendChild(selectionContents);
range.insertNode(mrk);
    return document.getSelection();
  }
}
```